# Using mirrored sample data to improve estimates

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, machine-learning

I will ask my question through an example game:

Each round we are given a blue coin and a red coin. We are either given a pair of fair coins or a pair of biased coins (these four coins are the set of all coins; there are no other coins).

For some valid reason, we have high confidence that these two biased coins are biased in *almost* the same way.

Let there be some small number $n$.

We go through $n$ rounds and observe the outcomes. In a particular round for example, the blue coin and red coin could land heads and tails respectively.

When we are trying to estimate $f_{X, Y}(x, y)$, does it make sense to add "mirrored" points to the sample data? In other words, for each pair of blue and red flips, should we add a "mirrored" data point where we say the result of the blue flip was what the red flip actually was and we say that the result of the red flip was what the blue flip actually was?

Comment: What do you mean by "almost"?

Comment: "Almost" is left intentionally vague. To define it more concretely, let the probability of heads for the biased blue coin be $\mathbb P_{blue}(H) = r$ where $r$ is a number between [0, 1], and let the probability of heads for the biased red coin be $\mathbb P_{red}(H) = r + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is some small number in the range [0, 1 - r]. 

The real question here is: How small does $\epsilon$ need to be for "mirroring" sample data to be a good strategy?